# Why is the same SQL sometimes report errors, some time it runs fine?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the SQL statement:

```
select 
    ua.*, uuu.user_name 
from
    (select 
         ud.dev_id, 
         (select uud.user_id as user_id 
          from user_device uud 
          where ud.dev_id = uud.dev_id and assigned = 1) user_id,
         (select count(1) 
          from user_device du 
          where du.dev_id = ud.dev_id) user_number, 
         de.license
     from 
         user_device ud 
     inner join 
         device de on ud.dev_id = de.dev_id 
     where ud.user_id = 'XXXXXX') ua 
left join 
    user_info uuu on uuu.user_id = ua.user_id
```

Execute the same SQL, it sometimes reports this error, but sometimes it runs just fine.

The error :

[image: error]

and this is what I want (with another user_id yesterday)

[image]

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: You have a subquery which returns more than one row and it is being used somewhere which expects a single value.  My guess is that your underlying data may have changed over time, which is why it sometimes fails and other times passes.

Comment: 按照理论子查询不应该有两个返回值，是项目都一处逻辑错误导致返回多值。

Comment: Well at least you're using simplified Chinese and not traditional :-)  Check out Gordon's answer which seems to be correct.

Comment: hh,sorry,I wrote in wrong place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory.  I'm pretty sure it is referring to this subquery:

```
 (select uud.user_id
  from user_device uud
  where ud.dev_id = uud.dev_id and assigned = 1
 )
```

Clearly, this subquery is returning multiple rows under some circumstances.  A quick and dirty fix is to add `and rownum = 1` to the `where` clause.

You can determine where the duplicates are by running:

```
select uud.dev_id, count(*) as cnt
from user_device uud
where uud.assigned = 1
group by uud.dev_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: but why it can run ''sometimes''?

Comment: add and rownum = 1 to the where clause.it is runnable.

Comment: @JOLee . . . Because some user ids produce zero or one rows for the subquery.